# Resolving conflicts between multiple copies of boostrap plugins on the same page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I support a portal that uses proxy injection to include a Bootstrap nav bar on each page served up by the portal. When injected, the nav bar brings along a stripped down set of the Bootstrap plugins so it can function on the page it is injected into.

Initially we had no issues but now application developers are beginning to use various frameworks and native bootstrap to create apps and content, which is causing a conflict with the injected nav bar. I've created a function to look for bootstrap on the injected page, and if found skip injecting our stripped down plugin library. And it works just fine. The problem is that each framework is different enough that I am writing a test case for each one and I am afraid I'll have to keep adding test cases as new frameworks are used. I have no control over what app developers choose to use to develop their content.

I attempted the fix on the Bootstrap site:

```
var myCollapse = $.fn.collapse.noConflict()
$.fn.collapse = myCollapse
```

But when included in my injected content is returning an error "cannot read property noConflict of undefined".

Could someone provide/point me to a solid walk through of how & when to implement the noConflict? Will this technique even work in this scenario?

Comment: Your 2-line code snippet doesn't mention `noConflict` anywhere...

Comment: Apologies, I did not edit the example from bootstrap's documentation correctly. I've fixed it.